# Php-SSRS DataSource Credentials

Tags: php, symfony, reporting-services

I'm using a third-party extension in Symfony to connect to SSRS: https://github.com/ChartBlocks/php-ssrs

I need to keep my SSRS datasource as "prompt for credentials" since we are also using another solution that requires that, but I'm unsure how to set the DataSourceCredentials in my solution.  I get the error: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: One or more data source credentials required to run the report have not been specified.

Here's my code in my controller:

```
$options = [
    'username' => $this->getParameter('ssrs_user'),
    'password' => $this->getParameter('ssrs_password')
];

$ssrs = new SSRS\Report($this->getParameter('ssrs_server'), $options);
$result = $ssrs->loadReport($this->getParameter('ssrs_base').'/'.$request->get('report'));

$ssrs->setSessionId($result->executionInfo->ExecutionID);
$parameters = json_decode($request->get('parameters'),true);
$ssrs->setExecutionParameters(new SSRS\Object\ExecutionParameters($parameters));

$output = $ssrs->render('HTML4.0'); // PDF | XML | CSV | HTML4.0 | Excel
return $output;
```

Anyone know what I need to add to pass the DataSourceCredentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer by creating my own method in the Report.php file, until it's updated in the core:

```
public function setDataSourceCredentials($datasource,$username,$password) {
    $this->checkSessionId();

    $options = array(
        'Credentials' => array(
            'DataSourceCredentials' => array(
                'DataSourceName' => $datasource,
                'UserName' => $username,
                'Password' => $password
            )
        )
    );

    $result = $this->getSoapExecution()->SetExecutionCredentials($options);
    return new ExecutionInfo($result);
}
```

I call this in my controller before rendering the report:

```
$ssrs->setExecutionParameters(new SSRS\Object\ExecutionParameters($parameters));
$ssrs->setDataSourceCredentials($this->getParameter('ssrs_datasource'),$this->getParameter('ssrs_sql_user'),$this->getParameter('ssrs_sql_password'));
```